# Is it possible to clean up an HTML file with grep to extract certain strings?

Tags: bash, unix, grep

There is a website that I am a part of and I wanted to get the information out of the site on a daily basis. The page looks like this:

```
User1 added User2. 
User40 added user3. 
User13 added user71
User47 added user461
```

so on..

There's no JSON end point to get the information and parse it. So I have to `wget` the page and clean up the HTML:

```
<a href="/user1">User1</a> added <a href="/user2">user2</a>
```

Is it possible to clean this up even though the username always changes?

Comment: Yes, it is doable, though the tools listed in the tag are probably not the best for the job.  It depends, in part, on how uniform and civilized the data layout is.  If it is all on a single line with no unnecessary spacing, it is harder than if each line is as shown.  It depends also on the surrounding HTML; the `<head>` section, for example, can probably be ignored.  You have to deduce where the information is stored in the HTML and decide how to get at it.  But an HTML parser is likely to be best.  Ad hoc parsing may do the job, but be cautious about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would divide that problem into two:

**How to clean up your HTML**

Yes it is possible to use `grep` directly, but I would recommend using a standard tool to convert HTML to text before using `grep`. I can think of two (`html2text` is a conversion utility, and `w3m` is actually a text browser), but there are more:

- `wget -O - http://www.stackoverflow.com/ | html2text | grep "How.*\?"`
- `w3m http://www.stackoverflow.com/ | grep "How.*\?"`

These examples will get the homepage of [StackOverflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com) and display all questions found on that page starting with `How` and ending with `?` (it displays about 20 such lines for me, but YMMV depending on your settings).

**How to extract only the desired strings**

Concerning your username, you can just tune your expression to match different users (`-E` is necessary due to the extended regular expression syntax, `-o` will make `grep` print only the matching part(s) of each line):

```
 [...] | grep -o -E ".ser[0-9]+ added .ser[0-9]+"
```

This however assumes that users always have a name matching `.ser[0-9]+`. You may want to use a more general pattern like this one:

```
[...] | grep -o -E "[[:graph:]]+[[:space:]]+added[[:space:]]+[[:graph:]]+"
```

This pattern will match `added` surrounded by any two other words, delimited by an arbitrary number of whitespace characters. Or simpler (assuming that a word may contain everything but blank, and the words are delimited by exactly one blank):

```
[...] | grep -o -E "[^ ]+ added [^ ]+"
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you intent to just strip away the HTML-Tags?

Then try this:

```
sed 's/<[^>]*>//g' infile >outfile
```

Comment: `sed 's/<[^>]*>//g' file..txt > out.txt ; egrep -v '^[[:space:]]*$' out.txt`

Comment: that did the drink! Thank you!